# count of a value in a column in mysql database

Tags: sql, mysql

i have a large mysql database table in which one column contains values ranging  from 1 to 9 
what query can i give so that i can get the count of 1s and 2s and 3s ... 9s in that column in the database ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select column, count(*) from table group by column
```

Answer (score 2):

You use grouping:

```
select TheValue, count(*)
from TheTable
group by TheValue
order by TheValue
```